# How to display the array value in a MatTableDataSource html

Tags: angular, angular-material, datasource

I'm trying to diplay "pat_nom" in my view  .

app.component.ts:

```
getPatient() {
    this.prescriptionService.getPrescription().then((result: Patient[]) => {
        if(!result){
            return;
        }
         this.dataSource= new MatTableDataSource(result);

        }
    )
```

app.component.html :

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="pat_nom">
    <th class="nom sortable" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        <div>Nom Prénom</div>
    </th>
    <td class="nom" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.patients.pat_nom}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Patient.ts :

```
export interface Patient {
pat_nom: string;
pat_prenom: string;
pat_date_naissance:Date;
prescriptions: Array<string>;
ind_obs: number;
ind_iah: number;
ind_fuites: number;
```

}

Result of my service in json :

```
"patients": [
{
  "ind_obs": "178",
  "ind_iah": 2.75,
  "pat_date-naissance": "1957-02-23 00:00:00.0",
  "pat_prenom": "François",
  "ind_fuite": 2.75,
  "pat_id": "4405",
  "prescriptions": [
    {
      "pres_type": "PPC"
    },
    {
      "pres_type": "PPC"
    }
  ],
  "ind_niveau": 2,
  "pat_nom": "ANDRE"
},
```

I'm trying to diplay "pat_nom" in my view  . i think that i have probleme with this

```
   <td class="nom" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.patients.pat_nom}} </td>
```

i can't acess to pat_nom.

[my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TcTO.png)

Comment: you have a spelling mistake. its `pat_prenom`  not `pat_nom`

Comment: no , i have pat_nom & pat_prenom in model Patient.But me i want to display pat_nom

Comment: I cant see `pat_nom` in your service response.

Comment: just a error of copy and paste .I edit my code know

Comment: Please share the code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular)

Comment: @DeepuReghunath i can't because that's not a simple component angular.Is portlet liferay with angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user123456 i find the solution to my probleme  :

prescription.serivce.ts :

```
 private extractData(res: Response): any {
    const body = res;
    return body || {};
}

public getPrescription(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable<any>(observer => {
        Liferay.Service(
            '/archipel.prescription/get-list-prescriptions',
            {
                qPatient: 'ANDRE',
                qMedecin: '144',
                qType: 'PPC',
                start: -1,
                end: -1
            },
            function (obj: any) {
                return observer.next(obj);
            }
        )
    });
}


   getPatientService(): Observable<any> {

    return this.getPrescription().pipe(map(this.extractData),
        catchError(this.handleError));
}



private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): any {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
        console.error(
            `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
            `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }`enter code here`
    return throwError(
        'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
}
```

app.component.ts :

```
export class AppComponent {


public pageSize = 10;
public currentPage = 0;
public totalSize = 0;
params: LiferayParams;
labels: any;
filtre: string = "";
count: number = 1;
displayedColumns: string[] = [
    "pat_nom",
    "pat_date_naissance",
    "prescriptions",
    "ind_obs",
    "ind_iah",
    "ind_fuites",
];


patients: Patient[] = [];
tableDataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

  getPatient() {
    this.prescriptionService
        .getPatientService()
        .subscribe((result: any) => {
            this.patients = result.patients
            this.tableDataSource.data = this.patients;
     
        });
}
```

app.component.html :

```
<table id="fileActive" mat-table [dataSource]="tableDataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8" >

<ng-container matColumnDef="pat_nom">
    <th class="nom sortable" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        <div> Nom</div>
    </th>
    <td class="nom" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.pat_nom }} {{element.pat_prenom}} </td>
</ng-container>


<ng-container matColumnDef="pat_date_naissance">
    <th class="naissance sortable date" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        <div> Né(e)le</div>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.pat_date_naissance | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy' }} </td>
</ng-container>


<ng-container matColumnDef="prescriptions">
    <th class="act" *matHeaderCellDef>
        <div>Activités prescrites</div>
    </th>

    <td class="act" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <div class="align">
            <div *ngFor="let a of element.prescriptions"
                 [ngClass]="{'vent': a.pres_type === 'Vent',
        'o2':a.pres_type === 'O2',
        'aidt':a.pres_type === 'Aidt',
        'aero':a.pres_type === 'Aéro',
        'perf':a.pres_type === 'Perf',
        'nut':a.pres_type === 'NUT',
        'ppc':a.pres_type === 'PPC'}">
                {{a.pres_type}}

            </div>
            </div>


    </td>

</ng-container>


<ng-container matColumnDef="ind_obs">
    <th class="obs sortable obsv" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        <div>Obs.</div>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <div [ngClass]="displayObsCss(element.ind_niveau)">
            {{element.ind_obs}}
        </div>
    </td>
</ng-container>


<ng-container matColumnDef="ind_iah">
    <th class="iah sortable obsv" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        <div>
            IAH
        </div>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ind_iah}} </td>
</ng-container>


<ng-container matColumnDef="ind_fuites">
    <th class="fuites sortable obsv" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        <div>
            Fuites
        </div>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ind_fuite}} </td>
</ng-container>


<ng-container matColumnDef="Renouvellement">
    <th class="renew" *matHeaderCellDef>
        <div>
            Renouvellement
        </div>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{element.Renouvellement | date }} </td>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="Valider_AR">
    <th class="valid" *matHeaderCellDef>
        <div>
            Valider AR
        </div>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="element.Valider_AR"
                      [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></mat-checkbox>
        <span>A Renouveler </span>
    </td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing {{element.pat_nom}} because the datasource is the entire array and pat_nom is one element of it.

Comment: could you please do "console.log(JSON.stringify( this.dataSource))" and show me what it prints?

Comment: could you please post the getPrescription() method as well?

Comment: {"patients":[{"ind_obs":"178","ind_iah":2.75,"pat_date-naissance":"1957-02-23 00:00:00.0","pat_prenom":"François","ind_fuite":2.75,"pat_id":"4405","prescriptions":[{"pres_type":"PPC"},{"pres_type":"PPC"}],"ind_niveau":2,"pat_nom":"ANDRE"},{"ind_obs":"178","ind_iah":2.75,"pat_date-naissance":"1957-08-16 00:00:00.0","pat_prenom":"Lionel","ind_fuite":2.75,"pat_id":"4406","prescriptions":[{"pres_type":"PPC"},{"pres_type":"PPC"}],"ind_niveau":2,"pat_nom":"ANDRE"},{"ind_obs":"178","ind_iah":2.75,"pat_date-naissance":"1941-05-24 00:00:00.0","pat_prenom":"Marie-Lourdes","ind_fuite":2.75,"

Comment: i don't have method getPrescription()

Comment: this.prescriptionService.getPrescription() <---- this one in the service class where you get the data

Comment: public getPrescription(){
        var instance = this;
        return new Promise<Patient[]>((resolve) => {if (!instance.cache) {  Liferay.Service(
                    '/archipel.prescription/get-list-prescriptions',
                    {qPatient: 'ANDRE',  qMedecin: '144', qType: 'PPC', start: -1,end: -1           },
                    function (obj: any) {
                        instance.cache = obj;
                        resolve(instance.cache);

                    }
                );
            }
            else { resolve(instance.cache)     }  });

Comment: could you try changing this line ```return new Promise<Patient[]>``` to this ```return new Promise<Array<Patient>>``` and put {{element.pat_nom}} not {{element.patiens.pat_nom}}

Comment: i do'it but i have alway the same probléme i can't display pat.nom in my html i do like this {{element.patients.pat_nom}}

Comment: do it like this {{element.pat_nom}}

Comment: Also, do the other values display and it's just pat_nom which doesn't?

Comment: no nothing is displayed, i try element.pat_nom it's dosn't work

Comment: could you please post the entire HTML file where you put the table?

Comment: <table id="fileActive" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8" >

    <ng-container matColumnDef="pat_nom">
        <th class="nom sortable" *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
            <div>Nom Prénom</div>
        </th>
        <td class="nom" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <span> {{element.pat_prenom}}</span> </td>
    </ng-container>

Comment: can you send a screenshot of the part of the table which shows on the page? Also, look if there's any error in the console when you try to access the page which has the table.

Comment: the requested image at the top. with name my_app

Comment: could you please put the components in https://stackblitz.com/ so I can give a look?

Comment: at least the table in html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8caieu?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: but i think is diffuclt to excute my code. because is portlet liferay

Comment: I'll try and see what I can do

Comment: It took some time but here is a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbmban?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html

Comment: from what I could see from the screenshot the data that you were receiving had more than just "patients". I created a json file with some data which you can change if you want.

Comment: i try you'r solution tha's work ,but in case i have more patients, they are displayed in a single line

Comment: I believe you have to include the loop I have commented out in the ts file